# Reading data to geopandas using WFS - GML format

Tags: python, geopandas, gml, pandas

This relates to the question here:
[Reading data to geopandas using WFS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299567/reading-data-to-geopandas-using-wfs)

Is there a way to to do the same with a service that does not supply the data in GeoJSON format, but in GML-format?

The webservice is:
https://arealinformation.miljoeportal.dk/gis/services/DAIdb/MapServer/WFSServer

And I want to read a single layer.

Comment: see [OWSLib:wfs](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/#wfs)

Answer (score 1):

```
import geopandas as gp
import requests
from fiona import BytesCollection    

def wfs2gp_df(layer_name, url, bbox=None, wfs_version="2.0.0", outputFormat='application/gml+xml; version=3.2'):
    params = dict(service='WFS', version=wfs_version,request='GetFeature', typeName=layer_name, outputFormat=outputFormat)
    with BytesCollection(requests.get(url,params=params).content) as f:
        df = gp.GeoDataFrame.from_features(f)
    return df

wfs2gp_df('your_wfs_layer_name', 'your_wfs_url').head()
```

Comment: Using `outputFormat=json` did the trick for me. For some reason I failed to import XML/GML into GeoPandas.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that the WFS server offers the json format

Comment: yes, that's correct. However, the server I'm working with can do that and I got results with JSON output. Obviously it would be great if XML/GML would work in my project.