# Select specific layer to read when reading data to GeoPandas using OWSlib

Tags: python, geopandas, wfs, owslib

I am trying to read a specific layer from a WFS service but can't figure out how to specify which the layer to read when using OWSlib.

The code was copied from: [Reading data to geopandas using WFS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299567/reading-data-to-geopandas-using-wfs)

The code mentions fetching the last layer. How can I fetch the 1st or lets say 3rd layer?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
from requests import Request
import fiona
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['WFS'] = 'r'

# URL for WFS backend
url = 'https://service.pdok.nl/kadaster/bestuurlijkegebieden/wfs/v1_0?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS'

# Initialize
wfs = WebFeatureService(url=url)


# Fetch the last available layer (as an example) --> 'vaestoruutu:vaki2021_5km'
layer = list(wfs.contents)[-1]

# Specify the parameters for fetching the data
# Count: specificies amount of rows to return (e.g. 10000 or 100)
# startIndex: specifies at which offset to start returning rows
params = dict(service='WFS', version="1.0.0", request='GetFeature',
      typeName=layer, outputFormat='json', count=1000, startIndex=0)

# Parse the URL with parameters
wfs_request_url = Request('GET', url, params=params).prepare().url

# Read data from URL
data = gpd.read_file(wfs_request_url)

return
```

I updated the WFS to the version 2.0 that you provided.
Changing the the index of the layers doesn't change the layer the layer read at the end. I am trying to read 'Provinciegebied' Do you know why this might be happening?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from requests import Request
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService

# URL for WFS backend
url = 'https://service.pdok.nl/kadaster/bestuurlijkegebieden/wfs/v1_0?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS'

# Initialize
wfs = WebFeatureService(url=url)

# Fetch the last available layer (as an example) --> 'vaestoruutu:vaki2021_5km'
layer = list(wfs.contents)[1]

# Specify the parameters for fetching the data
# Count: specificies amount of rows to return (e.g. 10000 or 100)
# startIndex: specifies at which offset to start returning rows
params = dict(service='WFS', version="2.0.0", request='GetFeature', typeName=layer, outputFormat='json', count=1000, startIndex=0)

# Parse the URL with parameters
wfs_request_url = Request('GET', url, params=params).prepare().url

# Read data from URL
data = gpd.read_file(wfs_request_url)
```

Comment: `https://service.pdok.nl/kadaster/bestuurlijkegebieden/wfs/v1_0?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS` gives you a WFS version 2.0.0 response, but you are requesting version 1.0.0 in your params the GetCapabilities of which is:  `https://service.pdok.nl/kadaster/bestuurlijkegebieden/wfs/v1_0?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS&version1.0.0`  version 1.0.0 WFS doesn't support paging

Comment: Please see update.

Comment: When I use `url = 'https://service.pdok.nl/kadaster/bestuurlijkegebieden/wfs/v1_0?'`
`wfs = WebFeatureService(url=url, version='2.0.0')` I get... `0   provinciegebied.ab06abc7-1d7f-4fbe-b7aa-5563f1...  ...  MULTIPOLYGON (((265275.541 549247.459, 265285....`

Comment: Thanks! I was missing version='2.0.0' from wfs = WebFeatureService(url=url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pure Python problem (lists)

With your WFS backend:

```
# list of all layers 
print(list(wfs.contents))
['Gemeentegebied', 'Provinciegebied', 'Landgebied']
#Fetch the last available layer
list(wfs.contents)[-1]
'Landgebied'
# or Fetch the third available layer
list(wfs.contents)[2]
'Landgebied'
# Fetch the first available layer
list(wfs.contents)[0]
'Gemeentegebied'
#Fetch the second available layer
list(wfs.contents)[1]
'Provinciegebied'
```